# Integrating the derivative of a multivariate function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

If $u=u(x,t)$ how do I compute $\displaystyle \int \frac{du}{dt}dt$ ?

Would I be correct in saying it is not simply a case of cancelling the $dt$'s and getting an answer of $u$+ constant, seeing as $u$ is a multivariate function?

Comment: It is crucial to know whether $x$ is constant or not along the integral.

Comment: I'm not sure. I can write $u$ as $u=u(x(t),t)$  so $u$ is purely a function of $t$, but this doesn't imply $x$ is constant?

Answer (score 0):

What does the integration mean?

Integration with one variable $t$ is an *operation* acts on a function with *the* variable $t$

So $\int \frac{d}{dt}u(x,t) dt$ means nothing more than we integrate the function $\frac{d}{dt}u(x,t)$ with respect to $t$ with $x$ fixed. If $x$ was a function  of a variable $t$, then it must have been noted before one uses the integrations. However, it's not the case.

Hence, it is just $F(x)=\int \frac{d}{dt}u(x,t) dt$. And to emphasize that $x$ is fixed under the integration, set $u_x(t):=u(x,t)$

Then, $F(x)=\int \frac{d}{dt}u_x(t) dt = u_x(t) + C = u(x,t)+ C$.

This is just the fundamental theorem of calculus.

I don't have time to write more so I hope you understand it now.

Comment: I understand what you have written. However would matters change if $u=u(x(t),t)$?

Comment: @lemony9201 Yes it matters it is a completely a different problem. When you do mathematics, you SHOULD NEVER assume more than what the question says. $u$ is a function, for example, it can have two different values $u(2,3),u(3,3)$. you can't restrict $x$ to be a function of $t$, since $2\neq 3$. You first need to answer yourself why you assume $x$ is a function of $t$.

Comment: @lemony9201 Think of the $xy-plane$ and a unit ball $B$ with radius 1 and a function $f$ integrable with respect to $x$. The integration in your post is merely saying, for each fixed $y$, you integrate $f$ with respect to $x$, Not the integration along some arbitrary curve in the ball $B$.

Comment: I don't think $\frac{d}{dt}u(x,t)$ even makes sense. How can you have a straight derivative of a function of two variables? $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x,t)$ does make sense. Also $\frac{d}{dt}u(x(t),t)$ makes sense as it is only a function of one variable.

Comment: @lemony9201 Read the definitions of differentiation and integration. And read my answer and comment carefully. I majored physics years ago so I know that lots of engineers and physicists don't give an attention to definitions and just **calculate**. Even I was like that 5yrs ago and I deeply regret that.

Comment: $u(x(t),t)$ is not a function of one variable. It is a function of 2 variables, one of which is also a function of the other.

Answer (score -1):

\begin{equation}
\frac{du}{dt}dt=du
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{du}{dt}dt= \int du
\end{equation}
Where
\begin{equation}
du=u_{x}dx+u_{t}dt
\end{equation}
Where
$$u_{x_{k}}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{k}}$$

Comment: Isn't it much better to say that $x$ acts as a constant? Can the equation $"du=u_x dx + u_t dt"$ be formalized?

Comment: Yes, that would be true but I thought that the OP was looking for something more rigorous. Practically though, you are correct that's exactly how one would compute an integral of that type.

Comment: No, I mean whether the equation $du=u_x dx + u_t dt$ can be formalized **without** introducing differential 1-form. Integrations such as that in OP's post can be computed directly by the chain rule, but lots of **elementary calculus** texts introduce equations such as $du=u_x dx + u_t dt$ and this misleads to think that $du/dt$ is an actual fraction and $du$ is an actual function and etc..

Comment: I'm asking this simce I'm curious myself. I don't know what $du=u_x dx + u_t dt$ actually means if this is not an 1-form equation.

Comment: Well I perhaps wouldn't view it as a 1-form but more as a total derivative. This would allow me to let the variables in question vary and not necessarily stay constant in all but one of them.

Comment: @Autolatry Ok ,but what is $\int du$, with $du=u_{x}dx+u_{t}dt$?

Comment: One would use Stoke's Theorem to compute $\oint_{\partial\Sigma}\left \{P\mathrm{d}x+Q\mathrm{d}t \right \}$.

Comment: I'm sure it is not as complicated as that, in my notes the next line is given without explanation. Does the fact that I can write $u(x,t)$ as $u(x(t),t)$ simplify things? My notes imply that $\displaystyle \int \frac{du}{dt}dt=$ $u$+constant but I don't understand why given we are considering a multivariate function.